# Не могу перенаправить трафик через iptables для 80 и 443 портов

Tags: ubuntu, ip, iptables

Необходимо перенаправить весь входящий трафик с сервера xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx на сервер yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy. А именно несколько портов: 80, 443, 8448. Сервера находятся в разных дата-центрах, у разных провайдеров. Порты 80 и 443 используются для сайта, 8448 для прокси-сервера. Ну и перенаправляется SSH порт.

Собственно, подключение к прокси-серверу по порту 4884 работает хорошо - никаких сбоев и проблем не возникает. А подключиться к сайту невозможно: ошибка `curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 80: Timed out`. Самое интересное, что подключение к поддомену сайта, DNS которого ссылается на первый сервер yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, открывается без проблем.

Правила iptables:

```
#!/bin/bash
export IPT="iptables"

# Внешний интерфейс
export WAN=eth0

# Очищаем правила
$IPT -F
$IPT -F -t nat
$IPT -F -t mangle
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -X

# Запрещаем все, что не разрешено
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP

# Разрешаем localhost и локалку
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Рзрешаем пинги
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# Разрешаем исходящие подключения сервера
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o $WAN -j ACCEPT

# разрешаем установленные подключения
$IPT -A INPUT -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -p all -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Отбрасываем неопознанные пакеты
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Отбрасываем нулевые пакеты
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Закрываемся от syn-flood атак
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# открываем доступ к SSH
#...

# редирект трафика на другой хост
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:443
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4884 -j DNAT --to-destination yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:4884

$IPT -A FORWARD -p tcp -d yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -p tcp -d yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -p tcp -d yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy --dport 4884 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

netfilter-persistent save > /dev/null 2>&1
netfilter-persistent reload > /dev/null 2>&1
```

tcpdump на сервере xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:

```
root@proxy:~# tcpdump -ttt 'host mysite.com and port not 4884'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
 00:00:00.000000 IP proxy.51365 > mysite.com.https: Flags [S], seq 3742067694, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
 00:00:00.001793 IP proxy.51364 > mysite.com.https: Flags [S], seq 3229825913, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
 00:00:00.248373 IP proxy.51366 > mysite.com.https: Flags [S], seq 1299602852, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
^C
3 packets captured
8 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

На сервере же yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, где находится сайт и прокси сервер, нет никаких логов с **iptables** и **tcpdump**, что кто-то стучится на порт 80 или 443 с ip сервера (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) или моего адреса, с которого пытаюсь открыть сайт.

Возникает вполне логический вопрос: почему трафик для SSH и прокси перенаправляется и работает без проблем, а порты 80 и 443 - нет?

Comment: Данные извращения необходимы, чтобы обойти блокировку РКН адресов DigitalOcean. Быть может есть иные варианты обхода блокировки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема на стороне хостера. Сменил провайдера и все заработало.